When exporting a spreadsheet as a PDF using AppScript, how do you include the current date and time?
What, if any, is the keyword argument to include in url to show the current date and time when exporting a spreadsheet as a PDF in AppScript? This option is possible when clicking File > Download > PDF so I would have thought it was possible through the script too.
I've tried timestamp=true but that didn't work

You need to programmatically add the current date and time to the file name, as there is no direct keyword argument like timestamp=true for this purpose.
Here’s an example of how you can add the current date and time to the file name when exporting a Google Sheets spreadsheet as a PDF with Apps Script:
function exportSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
 
  // Get the current date and time
  var now = new Date();
  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(now, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss');
 
  // Prepare the export URL
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheet.getId() + '/export?';
 
  var exportOptions = {
    format: 'pdf',
    size: 'letter',         // Paper size
    portrait: true,         // Orientation
    fitw: true,             // Fit to width
    top_margin: '0.50',     // Margins
    right_margin: '0.50',
    bottom_margin: '0.50',
    left_margin: '0.50',
    gridlines: false,       // Whether to print gridlines
    printtitle: false,      // Whether to print title
    pagenum: 'CENTER',      // Page number position
    attachment: false,
    gid: sheetId,           // Sheet ID
  };
 
  // Append export options to the URL
  for (var key in exportOptions) {
    url += key + '=' + exportOptions[key] + '&';
  }
 
  // Get the PDF content
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    },
  });
 
  var pdfBlob = response.getBlob().setName('Export_' + timestamp + '.pdf');
 
  // Save the PDF to Google Drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('your-folder-id'); // Replace with your folder ID
  folder.createFile(pdfBlob);
}

